# Error creating directory with specific name android

Tags: android

I need to create 2 directories in my android application,
I can use this code to create a directory just fine

```
File m_Dir = new File(getFilesDir() + "/randomDir");
    m_Dir.mkdir();
    if (m_Dir.isDirectory()) {
        Log.w("tag","randomDir dir is a directory");
    }
```

however I cannot use this because it does not create a directory, no errors, but it just isn't a directory for some reason, even though the only thing that changed is the name of the file

```
File m_Dir = new File(getFilesDir() + "/dict");
    m_Dir.mkdir();
    if (m_Dir.isDirectory()) {
        Log.w("tag","dict dir is a directory");
    }
```

note they must be named "dict and "dbfiles", Using them for JWI wordnet, and thats how it locates the files it needs.
I have tried this many times with different names, and the only reason that this `m_Dir.isDirectory` returns false is because of the name, this doesn't make sense to me. The only reason I can think of, that this might fail is because I have file directories in my Assets folder with the same name.(I am copying these into my new directory so i can use them). I can change the name of the Asset folders (Probably what I'm going to do). However I created another folder in assets using a different name, I tried that name and it worked creating the directory using the same code as before. So that may not even be the problem.  I was wondering wondering why this problem is occurring (No errors but no directory) and if there is any better way around it?

Comment: The assets path should be different so that should have no bearing on it.

I say its more likely possible that your doing or did something that's causing dict to fail and need to remove, clean and/or reboot and/or check your code for something that's causing dict to fail.

You can also try dict on another device or in another sub dir, etc. and see what happens. I don't think anyone can give you a direct answer as there's too many unknowns.

Comment: @CmosBattery I tried a lot of different ways earlier using stuff with dict, so that would make sense. Ill give it a shot thanks!